# Cannot use having because it is not contained in an aggregate function, but cant solve because column is missing

Tags: sql, database

I am trying to complete this question, but I am receiving a "Column 'DOG.DOB' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause." error, but I am stuck because there is no age column and I am confused on how I'm supposed to go about solving it. Below is the question to the problem and below the question is the desired output

Using a subquery, create a query that will show those dogs that are older than the average age of all dogs.  In your output include the name of the dog and the age.  Since the database does not store the age of a dog, you will need to calculate it.  There are numerous functions that can help you to find the difference between two dates.  To get the current system date use the getdate() function.  Sort your output by the age of the dog showing the older dogs first.  Rename your columns:  Dog Name and Age.  This query will product 359 rows.  The first 10 rows will look like the following:

```
Dog Name                Age
--------------- -----------
Rosina                   10
Floris                   10
Harlin                   10
Martina                  10
Roselin                  10
Rem                      10
Alie                     10
Roxane                   10
Nester                   10
Clair                    10
```

**My Query:**

```
  select Name AS 'Dog Name', 
         DATEDIFF(year, getdate(), DOB) AS 'Age'
    from DOG
  having DATEDIFF(year, getdate(), DOB) > avg(DATEDIFF(year, getdate(), DOB))
order by AGE desc
```

Comment: Should "where" be used instead of "having"?

Answer (score 0):

the average calculation needs to be in it's own select statement - which will form the subquery mentioned in the question e.g.

```
having DATEDIFF(year, getdate(), DOB) > (subquery returning the average age of all dogs)
```